# Hide the title or Change the Title style of one page based on page Title Multi site

Tags: 7, theming

I know that I can hide the title by using:

```
.page-node-43 h1
{ display: none;}
```

The problem with that is that I am using this css file for all of the websites that I am using. The websites have **different node numbers** for sometimes the same kind of page.
So there is the catch.

I want something like

```
.page-practial h1
{ display: none;}
```

But that doesn't work.
Do I have to use to achieve this? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to determine which pages do or do not have a title on node creation or can you go back in at a later time to disable titles? Are you using path aliases where certain sections will not show a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a multi-site, you could just use the domain and add it to the body class. That way you can target the same content type differently on each site.

Using preprocess_html...

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  global $base_url;

  // Split the URL
  $site_host = explode('/', $base_url);

  // Split the root domain from the TLD (.com).
  $site_host = explode('.', $site_host[2]);

  // Add it to your body class.
  $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($site_host[0]);
}
```

You might have to alter it a bit, but you get the idea. So if your domain was `http://example.com`, this would add `example` to the body class.

```
<body class="page-node page-node- page-node-194 node-type-product example">
```